# My FPDF display error on online server but on localhost evrything goes well

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, mpdf

Hello I have realy wird Problem with FPDF. Online server display that error

> Can't open file
> G:\xamp\htdocs\awww\Praca\testing/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf

I don't know why the path is set from my localhost :/. I tryed set fonth path like that `define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/font');` ,but after this webpage had not display

> Webpage [www.instafashion24.com](http://www.instafashion24.com) not working
>
> The server can now [www.instafashion24.com](http://www.instafashion24.com) not handle this request.

> HTTP Error 500

Any suggestions  what is going wrong ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

This is not FPDF but tFPDF and you need to remove/recreate the font-cache file in /font/unifont because they were created with absolute pathes. Just remove all files *.cw.dat and *.mtx.php and make sure that the folder is writeable so that new cache files can be created.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the files cache files is wrong in my opinion, if different applications are generating new cache ones. We found adding an absolute path to the *.mtx.php worked for us.

Open the *.mtx.php file and add $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to the $ttffile variable.

$ttffile=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pathtofonts/font/unifont/example.ttf';

Comment: XD forgot about this. It was probably xampp configuration problem. No longer use it

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use an absolute path instead of relative path for the font.